# Exchange the bytes

Tags: c

I want to exchange the bytes of a number. Example the binary representation of a number is
 `00000001 00011000 00000100 00001110`. I want to reverse it: `00001110 00000100 00011000 00000001`.

Can you please help? The current code is below:

```
void showBits(int n)
{
    int i,k,andMask;
    for(i=15;i>=0;i--)
    {
        andMask=1<<i;
        k=n&andMask;
        k==0?(cout<<"0"):(cout<<"1");
    }
}
int reverse(int a)
{
    int b=a<<8;
    int c=a>>8;
    return (b|c);
}
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    showBits(a);
    int b=reverse(a);
    showBits(b);
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I took the 15 bit represention of number.The proram is as                                                                                   void showBits(int n)
{
   int i,k,andMask;
   
   for(i=15;i>=0;i--)
   {
       andMask=1<<i;
       k=n&andMask;
       
       k==0?(cout<<"0"):(cout<<"1"); 
   } 
}                                                                                     int reverse(int a)
{
   int b=a<<8;
   int c=a>>8;
   return (b|c); 
}

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    showBits(a); 
    int b=reverse(a);
    showBits(b);
    cin.get();
}

Comment: Some of your bytes are 9 bits

Comment: I updated the question with the code you provided.

Comment: You can't use `cin` and `cout` for I/O if you're coding in C; those are C++ constructs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply reverse a 32-bit number, you can use a bit-shifting technique that isolates each byte region using bit-masks and logical `AND`, and  then swaps those bytes by the appropriate number of shifted bits using the bit-shift operators `>>` and `<<`.  You can then recombined the bits using logical `OR` like so:

```
int temp = 0x12345678;
temp = ((0xFF & temp) << 24) | ((0xFF00 & temp) << 8) | ((0xFF0000 & temp) >> 8) |
       ((0xFF000000 & temp) >> 24));
```

You'll now end up with a final value in `temp` of `0x78563412`.

**Update:** Okay, I'm looking over you code, and noting the following:

1. The size of `int` it seems like you're wanting to work with from the binary digit you have posted is 32-bits ... so your `showBits` function is not cycling through enough bits to display an entire 32-bit integer. As far as I can see right now, it will only show up to the 16 lower bits.  So you'll need to be clear on whether you're working on a platform that defines `int` as 16 or 32-bits.
2. Your `reverse` functions is not correct.  If you have a 32-bit `int` like `0x12345678`, and you shift it left by 8-bits, you will end up with `0x34567800`.  Likewise, when you shift it right by 8-bits, you will just end up with `0x00123456`.  Shifting a number does not rotate the values through their respective positions (i.e., a shift left of 8-bits would not give you `0x34567812`).  Plus, even if it did, the logical `OR` of the rotated values would still not be a correct reversal of the values.  Instead, you must use the technique described above that uses bit-masks and logical `AND` to isolate each byte, and then shift those bits the appropriate number of places in order to reverse the bits in a 32-bit word.

Comment: Tell me, where in the standard does it specify that `int` is 32 bits?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't ... but the OP displayed a 32-bit binary number, so I just assumed that was the definition of an `int` on his platform.  I'll fix that ...

Comment: It's alright. I'm trying to figure out a good way to write something that works for arbitrarily-sized objects. About the only thing I can come up with is `#define reverse(x) (sizeof(x) == 1 ? (x) : sizeof(x) == 2 ? /* swap 2 bytes */ : sizeof(x) == 4 ? /* swap 4 bytes */ : /* swap 8 bytes */)` but that's rather ugly and prone to breakage. (Of course you could do it more cleanly if you changed `reverse` to take two parameters, the second one being the output variable, but that's a rather ugly calling convention.)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
result = ((number & 0xFF) << 24) | ((number & 0xFF00) << 8) | 
   ((number & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((number & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int myInt = 0x012345678

__asm {
  mov eax, myInt
  bswap eax
  mov myInt, eax
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote you or tie you to a stake and burn you.

Comment: gcc also has a builtin swapbytes which does the same but supports different architectures. you could also use the network address translation api of host system of your choice... but assembler is fun :D

Answer (score 0):

If your original task to to convert from machine-specific byte order to big endian and back, take a look at the hton* and ntoh* functions.

http://minix1.woodhull.com/manpages/man3/hton.3.html